# How to get complete solution for Rubik's Cube from kociemba Library

Tags: solver, rubiks-cube

I tried kociemba library in python,
And here is my code

```
import kociemba

cube = "rorrybobogwyrrgwyobryybggoowygwwbrgbyywoogbrrbbgwgwyow"
print(cube)

cube = cube.replace('y', 'U')
cube = cube.replace('r', 'R')
cube = cube.replace('b', 'F')
cube = cube.replace('w', 'D')
cube = cube.replace('o', 'L')
cube = cube.replace('g', 'B')

print(cube)

solution = kociemba.solve(str(cube))
print(solution)
```

And the output is **U D' L2 U' F' R' F L B L2 B D F2 U F2 D2 B2 D B2 R2 U**,
But applying this sequence of steps in my rubik's cube doesn't completely solve it, Can somebody please suggest any corrections to completely solve my cube from any scrambled state, I really don't need to solve under 20 steps and all, it can be even 50 steps, but I need complete solution for the cube

Comment: How would you solve the cube yourself? Implement it that way... Or implement some of the algorithms out there, like Thistlewaite's algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, I'm Actually building a Rubik's Cube solver Robot, So I need the robot to solve from any scrammbled state, I will be looking at Thistlewaite's algorithm, Thank You!

Comment: So you know how to solve the cube yourself? If so, implement that idea? If not, why not take the opportunity to learn how to do it?

Comment: Absolutely, I manually know how to solve it, But making a machine to solve it, I need to learn those things, Thanks a lot for your help!